# Which modular forms correspond to abelian varieties?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I have seen in a few places in the literature that given a weight two modular form, we can find an abelian variety that have the same $L$-function. But I haven't been able to find a precise statement on this correspondance. So, my question is, given a modular form $f$, what conditions do we need if we want to associate it to an abelian variety? Where can I find a proof in the literature?

Comment: This is originally due to Shimura. You can look in chapter 8 of Shimura's "Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic forms" or for something a little more modern look at chapter 4 section 2 of Hida's book "Geometric modular forms and elliptic curves. The case k>2 can also be done due to Deligne.

Comment: I think that your claim is wrong, as it stands. What is true is that given a (classical) modular form $f$ of weight 2 you can attach to it an abelian variety $A_f$ over $\mathbb Q$ such that $L(A_f)$ equals $\prod_{\sigma}L(\sigma(f))$ where $\sigma$ runs over all embeddings of the coefficient field of $f$ into $\mathbb C$. If such coefficient field is $\mathbb Q$, then $L(A_f)=L(f)$.